# How do you run a Gradle task after IntelliJ imports a project from Gradle?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I'd like to be able to trigger the execution of a Gradle task right after IDEA imports my projects. Currently, I'm attempting to work around [IDEA-96615](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-96615) and [GRADLE-2198](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2198), but I have some other use cases, such as perhaps generating some source files.

Based upon the documentation from IDEA, I'm **not** running `gradle idea` prior to importing because that generates the old style of projects, not the directory based `.idea` one.

Comment: Does the list of gradle tasks not show up on a tab on the left?

Comment: They do show up, but I'd like for the task to be run as part of the import process, not an additional step.

Comment: +1, having the same issue: We need to make sure, all Java code is generated upon (re-)importing the gradle project, to allow IntelliJ IDEA to compile the project.

Comment: See: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-idea-ext-plugin/wiki#gradle-tasks-triggers-settings

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I'm misinterpreting what you want, but I'll give it a try.

(this solution works for `2016.2`, and I believe for `15`)

What you can do is go to `View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle`

Then, click the little Gradle symbol, and it'll let you execute a gradle task:
[image]

[image]

Hope this helps :)